# Where do I find the argument passed to setBounds: containing the CGRect, and how do I read it?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, ios-simulator, lldb

I have a problem where a bounds gets a NaN origin value during an animation and the stack trace is all UI/CA. My angle of attack is to set a symbolic breakpoint at setBounds: and have it break only when a NaN value is found.

I have a basic set of understanding around argument passing and such but I do not yet possess the necessary low level c/objc/asm knowledge. Thanks in advance for any hints on how to move on.

For reference, here's an example of a call

```
0x382a69:  xorps  %xmm0, %xmm0
0x382a6c:  movaps %xmm0, -0xa8(%ebp)
0x382a73:  movl   0xae1a83(%edi), %eax
0x382a79:  movl   %eax, -0xd0(%ebp)
0x382a7f:  movsd  -0xa8(%ebp), %xmm0
0x382a87:  movsd  -0xa0(%ebp), %xmm1
0x382a8f:  movsd  %xmm1, 0x10(%esp)
0x382a95:  movsd  %xmm0, 0x8(%esp)
0x382a9b:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
0x382a9f:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x382aa2:  calll  0xaff28a                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
```

and the start of setBounds:

```
QuartzCore`-[CALayer setBounds:]:
0x1b09c7f:  pushl  %ebp
0x1b09c80:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1b09c82:  pushl  %ebx
0x1b09c83:  pushl  %edi
0x1b09c84:  pushl  %esi
0x1b09c85:  subl   $0x4c, %esp
0x1b09c88:  calll  0x1b09c8d                 ; -[CALayer setBounds:] + 14
0x1b09c8d:  popl   %edi
0x1b09c8e:  leal   0x10(%ebp), %esi
0x1b09c91:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %ebx
0x1b09c94:  xorps  %xmm0, %xmm0
0x1b09c97:  ucomiss 0x18(%ebp), %xmm0
0x1b09c9b:  ja     0x1b09ca3                 ; -[CALayer setBounds:] + 36
```